# '!=' is no a prefix unary operator (SWIFT)

Tags: swift, parse-platform, operators

Having and issue with Swift and Parse, Following a tutorial online which has been updated to Swift1.2 but i am getting errors the tutorial is not. And nothing on the forums, or other issues. Have been able to find and fix a few minor issues thanks to here and other students. but this one has me stuck.

It is coming up with:-

if (self.object !=nil) {          '!=' is not a prefix unary operator"

```
var object: PFObject!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if (self.object !=nil) {

        self.dateField?.text = self.object["date"] as? String
        self.detailsField?.text = self.object["details"] as? String
    }else {
        self.object = PFObject(className: "incident")
    }

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
}
```

Comment: As explained in the referenced thread, you need spaces on *both sides* of the operator: `if (self.object != nil) ...`

Comment: The compiler is interpreting "! =" as if you are trying to use it as a unary operator. Provided the "!=" operator does exist in this language, you might find that adding a space between "!=" and "nil" will solve your problem. If not, surround both arguments with parantheses.

Answer (score 2):

Put a space between != and nil.